# Counting number of characters used in an external list of words

Tags: python-2.7

This is quite a basic question.
In a given list of encrypted words, I need to calculate the number of times, each symbol occurs; lets take `#` for an example. How do I do that? This is an imported list of words.

```
#+/084&"      
#3*#%#+  
8%203:  
,1$&  
!-*%  
.#7&33&
#*#71%  
&-&641'2  
#))85
9&330*
```

Comment: does it have to be python? A little shell script would do it faster: `grep -o "#" file | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

If `words` is your list of strings, for example,

```
In [1]: sum([s.count('#') for s in words])
Out[1]: 8
```

To count each character you could do:

```
In [2]: [(c, sum([s.count(c) for s in words])) for c in set(''.join(words))]
Out[2]:
[(':', 1),
 ('9', 1),
 ('8', 3),
 ('3', 6),
 ...
 ('%', 4),
 ('$', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your example list in the format given in your question in a file called `filename.txt` and you want to count all occurences of the character `#` you can do

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    num_occurences = 0
    for line in f:
        num_occurences += line.count('#')
    print num_occurences
```